# drawing an arrow inside node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code, can the red arrow and its text be inserted within a node at pos=.5 (beside the blue circle) of the blue line, instead of drawing it separately with a draw command

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, positioning, calc, intersections, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings, shapes, shapes.misc, shapes.symbols, shapes.geometric, patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (4,0) node [black, xshift=.93cm, yshift=0cm] {$Q$};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,8) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=.3cm] {$P$};
\draw [ultra thick,blue] (0,7.5) -- +(-50:5cm) node [pos=.5, circle, draw, blue, fill=blue, scale=0.4]{};
\draw [thick,red,-latex'] (2.08,5.92) node [red, xshift=.2cm, yshift=.04cm]{x} -- +(-140:.4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i show you how to do this with defining `aligned pin` in my answer to one of your previous question? you can also use simple `pin`. sorry, actually i don't understand your question well ...

Comment: You can certainly do that, e.g. with `path picture`. However, I am struggling to understand what that should be good for.

Comment: Use a `pin` for that. You don't need anything as fancy as the `aligned pin` style though, just a normal one.

Comment: Would you please tell me the code for pinning the arrow!

Comment: @TorbjørnT., suggestion for `aligned-pin` is based on one of previous op question. there are also shown, how to use simple `pin` as i also mentioned in my comment. i thing that this question is duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordinary pins can be found on p. 241 of the pgfmanual.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, positioning, calc, intersections, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings, shapes, shapes.misc, shapes.symbols, shapes.geometric, patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (4,0) node [black, xshift=.93cm, yshift=0cm] {$Q$};
\draw [thick,-latex](0,0) -- (0,8) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=.3cm] {$P$};
\draw [ultra thick,blue] (0,7.5) -- +(-50:5cm) node [pos=.5, circle, draw, blue,
fill=blue, scale=0.4,pin={[red,pin edge={red,thick,latex'-}]above right:x}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just one more modification please, can the pinned arrow be shifted x and y. I appreciate your answer very much.

Comment: @Hany It an but how much should it be shifted? If you do `\draw [ultra thick,blue] (0,7.5) -- +(-50:5cm) node [pos=.5, circle, draw, blue,
fill=blue, scale=0.4,pin={[red,xshift=4pt,pin edge={red,thick,latex'-}]above right:x}]{};` then there will be an additional xshift by 4pt.

Comment: This shifted the text attached to the arrow, not the arrow itself

Comment: @Hany Do you want to shorten the arrow? Then try e.g. `shorten <=5pt`. If you want to move it, try `shorten <=5pt,shorten >=-5pt` or something along these lines. All of that goes into the curly brackets of `pin edge={...}`.

Comment: That is what I want.

Comment: Just for the record for those who try these techniques; I tried both suggestions by marmot: i.e. path picture and pin. I tried also Zarko suggestion of using aligned-pin. All of these techniques work very fine. But I found that using the path picture method is easier in aligning the arrow than using the pin and align-pin methods. I appreciate very much marmot efforts and both suggestions; and also Zarko suggestion and answers to my previous  questions.